# Send specific packets with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient, packet

Hey. Is it possible to send a packet from a C# application without using sockets? I'd like to use WebClient or HttpWebRequest in order to send specifically formatted packets to a server. Examples I've seen tend to use UDP client. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "Specifically Formatted". HttpWebRequest is a .Net wrapper around the HTTP protocol which is not UDP in nature, so you can not customize the packets it sends other than modifying object data like headers, etc.

Comment: I see. Does that mean that there is no other way to send a more customized packet than what HttpWebRequest provides, without using sockets? thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Like for Wake on Lan? Then yes. This absolutely has to be done in Sockets... See if this example works for you...
http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/04/02/3858.aspx

Comment: I came across that but it uses sockets. I was just curious as to whether it could be done over HTTP, but obviously not. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [IPEndPoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ipendpoint.aspx) class, this is designed for sending data to an network endpoint by IP and port address.  Here is a simple example, see the link for more details and a longer example with error checking.

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
string payload = "<Enter Your Payload Here>";
IPEndPoint ep = new IPEndPoint("127.0.0.1", 1234); //IP + Port

Socket remoteServer = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(payload);
remoteServer.SendTo(data, data.Length, SocketFlags.None, ep);
```